# Gradle/Android - Select essential files to build

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-studio

Basically, I'm using an open-source library in my main project. The library is included by `compile project('<path-to-lib>')`. The trouble is, there're a lot of files/classes/resources which I don't really need. I only need a small subset of those. Instead of deleting redundant parts, is there any way for me to write Groovy/Gradle script to pick only essential parts for building? This way, ideally, I can make minimal changes to the library.

Comment: You could fork the project and adapt its build, or you add some logic to your build to repackage the artifact(s) that the project dependency gets resolved to.

Answer (score 0):

In the build file for the library you can tailor the source sets to your needs. In general you write something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      exclude 'some/unwanted/package/**'
    }
  }
}
```

I'm assuming this is a plain Java library. If it's an Android library, the android-library plugin also supports `exclude` syntax in source sets.

Here's a SO question for reference:

[Android Studio Exclude Class from build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build)

You can also read the Gradle docs for source sets at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet:java(groovy.lang.Closure) and the Java plugin at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html