# Android Studio exclude package from build

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to exclude some packages from build path as they are not required by that flavour

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build) link that says to exclude class

But that requires 'java' plugin. If I apply java plugin it says it is not compatible with android plugin. So how do I exclude package from build.

I am using 'com.android.application' plugin.

Edit: WHY ?

I have got Product A consisting of feature 1, feature 2, feature 3. Now we want to create Project B containing only feature 1. Project C containing only feature 2.

I was able to achieve it partially by creating variant. But the apk for Project B and Project C is nearly as big as Project A. I need a way to remove unused code. Is there any way to achieve this ? Or should I be taking another approach ?

Comment: The instructions in that link don't say anything about requiring the Java plugin. It should work fine.

Comment: When I use java{ exclude } it says Gradle DSL method not found: 'java()'. Solution for that requires you to apply plugin 'java'. If I do that it reports a error saying that java plugin is incompatible with android plugin

Comment: Sorry, I gave you bad information. What you want isn't implemented yet. I'm closing this as a duplicate of another SO question.

Comment: In the question OP wants to exclude resources, i want to exclude java package. I have edited the question as to why I want to do this. Is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do using Android Studio

Comment: This is still a duplicate of that question. The source set is the same entity no matter whether it refers to Java sources or resource files.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way that I can achieve the objective using Android Studio ?

Comment: There's no easy way to do what you want.