# Exclude file from compilation - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, compilation

How to ignore a java file in Android Studio so it does not try to compile it ? Is there an easy way such as a right-click ?

Comment: This question has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build

Comment: That answer appears to be outdated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same problem.