# Android Studio exclude class or file from jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, proguard

How to exclude class or any another file from jar library in `Android Studio Gradle`?

I tried to use this:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'com/imagpay/bU.class'
}
```

And this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'com/imagpay/bU.class'
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing helped. After adding new library to project get such error during release:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't read [/home/denys/Epos/app/libs/PMCore.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Can't process class [com/imagpay/bU.class] (Unknown verification type [19] in stack map frame))

Comment: please show your `build.gradle` code.

Comment: http://codeshare.io/vQmUH

Comment: After adding PMCore.jar got such problem

Answer (score -3):

I had same problem with my Gradle project. So far i didn't find any way to remove duplicate .class files from jar dependency inside app/gradle. So what i did :

- Extract .jar library
- Removed duplicate .class files
- Packed again into .jar
- Clean (Make project if required) and it worked.