# Android studio , with multi dex ,how to avoid zipexception ,duplicate entry of a class being used in library aar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my android studio project , i use flurry and volley sdk . Recently , i added a new sdk to my project as new module via aar .This library also uses flurry and volley .

So when ever i try to run my code , i end up with the below error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/flurry/sdk/gh.class

Any help to fix this issue will be highly appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`

Comment: are you using any jars for these libraries ?

Comment: Yes . That module build from aar , may use some flurry sdk as jars.Also in my project , i use flurry sdk as jars.

Comment: then there are multiple instance of same jars and thats the reason you are having duplicate entry exception. You have to maintain only single instance of the class files

Comment: please post your complete log report here.

Comment: Yeah but , if i remove jar from my project , it gives me compilation error saying not found. Also , the jar used in that aar file may be older too ??

Comment: Is there a any chance to exclude classes from aar file while packaging the apk ??

Comment: I got the same issue, one aar is using recyclerview jar. The only way i solved it was by adding all the classes of the aar manually to my project & removing the jar , so i could use the latest recycler view. I tried with exclude but still got some exception. I am just sharing my experience, there might be some other way to resolve it.

Comment: @Gautam thanks bro :) i cannot do that , its because that sdk is being provided by some clients

Comment: @Gautam , i got the answer for this question with help Ajinkya . This may help you . . Thanks all for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your build.gradle enable multidex

```
 defaultConfig {


             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
```

and in your application class use MultiDex.install(Context) lie this

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

        @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);
            MultiDex.install(this);
        }

    }
```

and try this as well

```
compile (project(':yoursdk')) { 
transitive = false 
}
```

Comment: I have already enabled multi dex .Actually its duplicate class exception while packaging the app . Do you think is there any way to exclude class file from aar while packaging the app in android-studio ?

Comment: yes you can exclude classes have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008492/android-studio-exclude-class-or-file-from-jar

Comment: also have you wrote this MultiDex.install(this); in code?

Comment: yes i do have tried the above solution to exclude the files .yet no help .

Comment: sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude 'com/flurry/sdk/gh.class'
            }
        }
    }

Comment: try to download it from maven instead of using jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106219/discussion-between-ajinkya-and-pradeep-k).