# temporarily remove a class file from build without deleting it

Tags: android, android-studio

When working on a new java class, sometimes I want to temporarily remove the class from the build to test out some of the other support code. So I comment out where I call the ctor for that new class in the code that will use that new class.

But if the class has some unresolved issues, that will prevent the whole app from building unless I delete that class java file from the build. But if that class is a work in progress, I do not want to remove it completely, I just want gradle to temporarily ignore it.

How can I mark that java class file temporarily so it is ignored by gradle when building the app but without deleting that file from the project?

Thanks,
-Andres

Comment: Are you using git?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build

Comment: thanks for the comments.  No, I was not using git so that was a nice reminder to start using it with Android Studio.