# Android Studio: how to exclude specific package of an depended library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, aar

For example, I want to replace the implementation of Mp4Extractor(a final class) in Exoplayer with my own version. How can I achieve this?

Something like (which does not exist now):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.4' {
    exclude package: 'com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.mp4'
}
```

This is different from excluding certain java classes in the source tree, but from the remote library.
P.S. I have already tried as suggested on https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies but it does not work.

```
implementation ( 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.4' ){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core', module: 'mp4'
}
```

The purpose is to patch the Mp4Extractor implementation in the library for new codec supporting without modifying other classes which use "com.google.android.exoplayer.extractor.mp4".

Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Exclude Class from build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build)

Comment: @robin did u find any solution for this?