# Exclude Kotlin files from gradle build in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I want to exclude Kotlin files within a folder from the gradle build in Android Studio. This works fine as long as the files are `.java` files but when converting them to Kotlin, the exclude command ignores the Kotlin files in the folder.

The following is used within my app modules `build.gradle` file to exclude the folder:

```
 sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude '**/folderToExclude'
        }
    }
}
```

I already checked the following link, but the suggested solution didn't work:

[How to exclude kotlin files from compiling with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376686/how-to-exclude-kotlin-files-from-compiling-with-gradle)

Comment: The 'correct' way is to file a feature request for AGP and/or Kotlin compiler.

Comment: I don't see how this question is different from *[How to exclude kotlin files from compiling with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64016332/192373)*. *`The suggested solution didn't work`* is not a reason in itself to open a separate question. If you are not satisfied with an answer, you can vote for the question, add comments, propose a bounty or spread the word via other channels.

Comment: I also met the issue. when apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android',  the exclude does not work. Very sad.

Answer (score 0):

try below :

```
exclude '**/*.kt'
```

It will exclude all file with extention .kt

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: i think your file name that u write is wrong check with the file name

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it works on my machine.

```
android {
    ...

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude '**/your_file_1.kt',
                        '**/your_file_2.kt',
                        '**/your_file_3.kt',
                        '**/your_file_4.kt',
                        '**/your_file_5.kt'
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This also does not work for me. The java files I excluded throw a ClassNotFoundException when accessing them in code but this is not true for the Kotlin files

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude paths matching pattern like:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude '**/TestExcludeClass.java'
            }

            kotlin {
                exclude '**/TestExcludeKotlinClass.kt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```