# How to exclude a Kotlin file?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I wish to exclude a Kotlin file from my build.

Trying something like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            exclude '**/Test.kt'
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't work, the file gets compiled.

I have searched endlessly and similar questions on StackOverflow have no working answer and zero activity,
and it's hard to believe that such a simple goal is so hard to achieve.

Comment: maybe not comment you want, but why do you have `.kt` files in your sources you don't want to compile?

Comment: @al3c I need to be able to easily exclude some files without deleting / restoring them and messing my version control

Comment: See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-exclude-kotlin-files-from-compiling-with-gradle/17018

Comment: @AlexCohn The link you added does not contain any working answer.

Comment: Oh, I know the link does not contain a *working answer*. The problem is, this is **the answer** up to date. Has a new/better answer than https://stackoverflow.com/a/54398253 become available since January 2019? OTH, in what is your *question* different from *[How to exclude kotlin files from compiling with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376686/how-to-exclude-kotlin-files-from-compiling-with-gradle)*? I know that SO is sometimes disappointing, but it cannot pull a miraculous answer out of the hat, when there has never been a rabbit inside.

Comment: @alexcohn In this case, create an answer that says "this is impossible" and mark as the accepted answer.

Comment: I read the upvoted answer, and it says exactly this, and even proposes kind of a workaround.

Comment: @AlexCohn So mark it as the accepted answer (it's impossible to exclude files from build), if I knew that clearly I certainly wouldn't have to ask this question again...
Right now the previous SO questions are dead and don't give any clear direction about this matter.

Comment: I can only accept an answer on a question that is mine. Alas, [@HeyAlex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826038/heyalex) is not myself.