# android gradle resources exclude file not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

android gradle resources exclude file not working. e.g.

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            resources {
               srcDir "../../src/foo/resources"
               exclude "../../src/foo/resources/META-INF/foo.xml"
            }
        }

     }
}
```

The foo.xml is not excluded.

version: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Your tree shows that `foo.xml` is excluded in `androidTest`. You might want to change it to the main android node `android`.

Comment: Do not get it. Could you explain in detail? thanks.

Comment: android { sourceSets { main { java { exclude "../../src/foo/resources/META-INF/foo.xml" } } } }
Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build

Comment: What I did is the same as the link you provided, resources instead of java.

Comment: You have to use not only androidTest but main too.