# Exclude a class in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to exclude a particular class from build but apparently it doesn`t work. This is how my gradle looks. Any solutions?

```
   android {
    sourceSets {    
            main {            
                java {
                    filter.excludes = [
                        'path/MyClass.java',
                      ]               
                }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701256/android-studio-exclude-class-from-build